# How to construct a solution to a homogeneous system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

given the system of linear equations

$\begin{array}{rrrrr}x_{1} & + & x_{2} & + & 2 x_{3} & = & 2 \\ 2 x_{1} & + & 5 x_{2} & - & x_{3} & = & 2 \\ 3 x_{1} & + & 6 x_{2} & + & x_{3} & = & 4\end{array}$

I found the solutions

$x=\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{8}{3}-\frac{11}{3} t \\ -\frac{2}{3}+\frac{5}{3} t \\ t\end{array}\right)$ ,

$y=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{6}{5} -\frac{11s}{5} \\ s\\ \frac{2}{5}+\frac{3s}{5}\end{array}\right)$

Now I have to construct a solution to the following homogenous system out of x and y:

$\begin{array}{rrrrr}x_{1} & + & x_{2} & + & 2 x_{3} & = & 0 \\ 2 x_{1} & + & 5 x_{2} & - & x_{3} & = & 0 \\ 3 x_{1} & + & 6 x_{2} & + & x_{3} & = & 0\end{array}$

How can this be done?

Comment: It is impossible to have $2$ parameters for a linear system of rank $2$

Comment: but it says that I should find solution x and y, while y should not be a multiple of x for the inhomogeneous equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both $x$ and $y$ are solutions of the original system, $x-y$ is a solution of the homogenous system.

Comment: can you explain to me why this hold true? Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: That was an answer, not a comment. Anyway, consider the first equation: $x_1+x_2+2x_3=2$. You know that $x$ is a solution of that equation, which means that $\left(\frac83-\frac{11}3t\right)+\left(-\frac23+\frac53t\right)+2t=2$. And you also know that $y$ is a solution, which means that $\left(\frac65-\frac{11}5s\right)+s+2\left(\frac25+\frac35s\right)=2$. But then$$\left(\left(\frac83-\frac{11}3t\right)-\left(\frac65-\frac{11}5s\right)\right)+\left(\left(-\frac23+\frac53t\right)-s\right)+2\left(t-\left(\frac25+\frac35s\right)\right)=2-2=0.$$So, $x-y$ is a solution of the homogenous equation.

Comment: how obvious, thanks a lot for your patience!